# Have To Manually Start Hadoop Cluster on GCloud

Tags: hadoop, google-cloud-platform

I have been using a Hadoop cluster, created using Google's script, for a few months.

Every time I boot the machines I have to manually start Hadoop using:

```
sudo su hadoop
cd /home/hadoop/hadoop-install/sbin
./start-all.sh
```

Besides scripting, how can I resolve this?

Or is this just the way it is by default?

(The first boot after cluster creation always starts Hadoop automatically, why not always?)

Comment: Which scripts are you using?

Comment: @DennisHuo had to search for Hadoop in the GCloud Launcher

Answer (score 0):

You have to configure using init.d.

[Document](http://www.datameer.com/documentation/display/DAS30/Starting+Hadoop+Cluster+at+boot+time) provide more details and sample script for datameer. You need to follow similar steps. Script should be smart enough to check all the nodes in the cluster are up before invoking this script using ssh.

Comment: It would be *much* simpler to use the GCloud Compute Java API and SSH.  And more readable.

Answer (score 0):

While different third-party scripts and "getting started" solutions like `Cloud Launcher` have varying degrees of support for automatic restart of Hadoop on boot, the officially supported tools are [bdutil](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/bdutil) as a do-it-yourself deployment tool, and [Google Cloud Dataproc](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/overview) as a managed service, both of which are already configured with `init.d` and/or `systemd` to automatically start Hadoop on boot.

More detailed instructions on [using bdutil here](https://cloud.google.com/hadoop/setting-up-a-hadoop-cluster).